# Dialog and Activity lifecycle

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog

I have an Activity that shows different kinds of Dialog; some are AlertDialog that can only be dismissed by the user others are ProgressDialog that monitor an AsyncTask and some are CustomDialog.
My question is what happens if Android decide to destroy my Activity and one of these dialog is shown? (I have nothing in onDestroy that dismiss the dialog because there are too many and in different classes.) Will the Dialog gets dismissed or I end up with a crash?

Comment: If the dialogs are running on the main ui thread then I would imagine they'd close without crashing.

Comment: After investigating this I think their state is saved and when you open again the activity they will open too.... Causing more problems !!!